# gtkmm manage/add vs smart pointers:

Tags: c++, object-oriented, gtk, smart-pointer

gtkmm provides lifetime management of widgets using

```
Gtk::Widget* aWidget = Gtk::manage(new Widget()); 

Gtk::Widget.add(*aWidget);
```

This delegates lifetime management of aWidget to its container widget.

We also have several types of smart pointers, particular the  C++ 11 smart pointers templates, which I use everywhere.

I find the manage/add syntax easier and cleaner to use, but it's not part of the C++ Standard, it's a gtkmm specific feature, which makes me think I should stick to std::shared_ptr, etc.

So I'm wondering what are the advantages/disadvantages of smart pointers vs the gtkmm manage/add model (aside from cases where you need the reference after the owner container has been deleted, or when you have a top level widget that has no containing widget).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Gtk::manage()` solves the specific problem of lifetime management for hierarchies of widgets. And it solves it well.

Smart pointers (`std::shared_ptr` in particular) have broader application range, and therefore will be less efficient when used to address this specific problem. Lifetime management for hierarchies of widgets can be solved with `shared_ptr`, but it will be:

- not as concise as using `manage()` (as you pointed out yourself);
- less efficient in terms of memory usage, since using `shared_ptr`s will introduce memory overhead: `shared_ptr` has a memory footprint of its reference to its reference-count, which will use size - as opposed to `manage()`, which uses variables such as `Gtk::Object.referenced_` that are part of your `Widget` base class already at all times. So, if you have a significant number of `Widgets`, that size difference might become an issue worth considering;
- not as mainstream as using `manage()` in gtkmm (which has quite a few consequences, including clarity and maintainability).

As of idea of favoring `std::shared_ptr` over `Gtk::manage()` because `shared_ptr` is part of C++ Standard, while `manage()` is not - I'm not sure it is going to be a game changer for average application, as by not using `manage()` you don't cut your dependency on Gtk anyways. So your application is not going to gain any better portability if you'd go for `shared_ptr`.

I would rather leverage native gtkmm API, for sake of clarity and efficiency.

P.S.: There is actually a smart pointer `Glib::RefPtr`, which handles lifetime management for certain gtkmm objects. Again, as it is a feature native to Glib, it leverages built-in facilities of `Glib::ObjectBase`, and is therefore more efficient then `std::shared_ptr` for certain applications, for the reasons explained in the 2nd point above.

Comment: Excellent, thorough answer.

Comment: `Glib::RefPtr` (not `GLib` as you typed) is _not_ for lifetime management of widgets. The maintainer of gtkmm is on record saying `RefPtr` is _only_ to be used when the API makes you use it - http://stackoverflow.com/a/29156111/2757035 - e.g. for types like `Adjustment` and `ListStore`. Users are not supposed to use it out of initiative, e.g. as a general-purpose smart pointer. That's what `manage()` is for... or a stdlib pointer, which btw they are considering for a future release as a potential replacement for `manage()`: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtkmm-list/2016-February/msg00009.html